# Istio Proxy unable to connect to Istio Pilot on EKS

Tags: kubernetes, istio, amazon-eks

I have installed bookinfo on EKS according to the instructions [here](https://istio.io/docs/setup/kubernetes/helm-install/#option-2-install-with-helm-and-tiller-via-helm-install) and [here](https://istio.io/docs/examples/bookinfo/).

While verifying that the application was installed correctly, i received `000` when trying to bring up the product page.  After checking my network connections VPC/Subnets/Routing/SecurityGroups, I have narrorwed the issue down to being an istio networking issue.

Upon further investigation, I logged into the istio-sidecar container for productpage and have noticed the following error.

```
[2019-01-21 09:06:01.039][10][warning][upstream] external/envoy/source/common/config/grpc_mux_impl.cc:41] Unable to establish new stream
[2019-01-21 09:06:28.150][10][warning][upstream] external/envoy/source/common/config/grpc_mux_impl.cc:240] gRPC config stream closed: 14, no healthy upstream
```

This led me to to notice that the istio-proxy is pointing to the `istio-pilot.istio-system:15007` address for discovery.  Only the strange thing was, the kubernetes `istio-pilot.istio-system` service does not seem to be exposing port `15007` as shown below.

```
[procyclinsur@localhost Downloads]$ kubectl get svc istio-pilot --namespace=istio-system
NAME          TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                                 AGE
istio-pilot   ClusterIP   172.20.185.72   <none>        15010/TCP,15011/TCP,8080/TCP,9093/TCP   1d
```

Infact none of the services from the `istio-system` namespace seem to expose that port.
I am assuming that this `istio-pilot.istio-system` address is the one used for gRPC and would like to know how to fix this as it seems to be pointing to the wrong address; please correct me if I am wrong.

**Relevant Logs**

istio-proxy

```
2019-01-21T09:04:58.949152Z info    Version root@6f6ea1061f2b-docker.io/istio-1.0.5-c1707e45e71c75d74bf3a5dec8c7086f32f32fad-Clean
2019-01-21T09:04:58.949283Z info    Proxy role: model.Proxy{ClusterID:"", Type:"sidecar", IPAddress:"10.20.228.89", ID:"productpage-v1-54b8b9f55-jpz8g.default", Domain:"default.svc.cluster.local", Metadata:map[string]string(nil)}
2019-01-21T09:04:58.949971Z info    Effective config: binaryPath: /usr/local/bin/envoy
configPath: /etc/istio/proxy
connectTimeout: 10s
discoveryAddress: istio-pilot.istio-system:15007
discoveryRefreshDelay: 1s
drainDuration: 45s
parentShutdownDuration: 60s
proxyAdminPort: 15000
serviceCluster: productpage
zipkinAddress: zipkin.istio-system:9411
```

Comment: Why do you think the discovery address is istio-pilot.istio-system:15007?

Comment: I don't necessarily think it is.. all I know is that is the address hard-coded into the istio-proxy.  It doesn't seem to exist in the cluster though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wanted to post the solution to my issue.

**Problem:**

EKS DNS was not properly working which is why none of the other solutions (while very good!!) worked for me.

**Cause:**

When an AWS VPC is first created VPC DNS settings are not properly setup for EKS.  The following VPC settings are required to be enabled by EKS.

- DNS resolution: Enabled
- DNS hostnames: Disabled  `<-- Default VPC Settings`

**Solution:**

Set `DNS hostnames` to `Enabled` and DNS begins to work as expected.

Answer (score 3):

Ignore the gRPC warnings they are not meaningful.  Make sure you did the `kubectl apply -f samples/bookinfo/networking/bookinfo-gateway.yaml`

If you do `kubectl exec $(kubectl get pod --selector app=ratings --output jsonpath='{.items[0].metadata.name}') -c istio-proxy -- ps -ef` you will see an entry like
`--discoveryAddress istio-pilot.istio-system:15011`.  That is the address the sidecar uses
to contact Pilot and SHOULD match an entry you see
using `kubectl -n istio-system get service istio-pilot`.

If the discoveryAddress matches a Pilot port you can test networking.  You can't easily *curl* on the discovery address but if you do `kubectl exec $(kubectl get pod --selector app=ratings --output jsonpath='{.items[0].metadata.name}') -c istio-proxy -- curl https://istio-pilot.istio-system:15011` and you get a timeout then there is a communication problem.

The discovery address comes from Istio configuration.  If you do `kubectl -n istio-system get cm istio-sidecar-injector` and the age is older than your Istio install there may have been a problem with upgrading an older Istio version.

Answer (score 1):

To verify that Istio works correctly, send a request to the `productpage` from another pod, e.g. from `ratings`:

```
kubectl exec -it $(kubectl get pod -l app=ratings -o jsonpath='{.items[0].metadata.name}') -c ratings -- curl productpage:9080/productpage | grep -o "<title>.*</title>"
```

The output should be: `<title>Simple Bookstore App</title>`

If you get the correct output, the problem is probably with your Ingress definitions.

Verify carefully that you followed the steps specified [here](https://preliminary.istio.io/docs/examples/bookinfo/#determining-the-ingress-ip-and-port) and [here](https://preliminary.istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/#determining-the-ingress-ip-and-ports).

Answer (score 0):

Sending you the link to [the Istio docs](https://istio.io/help/ops/traffic-management/proxy-cmd/#get-an-overview-of-your-mesh) which may be really helpful when debugging Istio.

Comment: This is a big help, but brings up a whole bunch of new issues... firstly the command `istioctl proxy-status` outputs nothing.